# Any diﬀerence between "give ﬁve dollars to him" and "give him ﬁve dollars"?

Tags: differences, syntactic-analysis, connotation, dative-alternation

This might be a most frequently asked question, but I am quite confused
about the diﬀerence between the transitive and the ditransitive usage of verbs
such as *give*, *write*, and *buy* which can take an indirect object or a prepositional phrase.

1. I wrote a letter to John. (*with prepositional phrase*)
2. i wrote John a letter.  (*with indirect object*)

In (1), the letter has already arrived and John now has the letter 
in his keeping.

In (2), it is not clear whether John has received the letter and now
possesses it, right?

Then, how about *give*?

3. I gave John ﬁve dollars. (*with indirect object*)
4. I gave ﬁve dollars to John. (*with prepositional phrase*)

I understand that in (3), it is apparent that John has got ﬁve dollars (meaning he possesses it, not that he has received it).

However, if the diﬀerence in (1) and (2) is applicable here, we would
expect that (4) means either

- (i)  John has got ﬁve dollars.

or

- (ii) John has not got ﬁve dollars.

The question is: Is it possible to interpret (4) as (ii)?

I ﬁnd it confusing because I think as soon as someone *give* something to
someone the receiver gets the thing.  I really appreciate any answer,
suggestion, or intuition.

Comment: They mean essentially the same thing.  The difference is in emphasis -- the thing named first usually receives more attention.  Of course, whether John still has the five dollars or spent it on booze is impossible to answer.

Comment: @David I'm guessing (and the comments have now gone), but it's often considered the least of three evils to close-vote and give an answer in 'comments' (less than CV-ing _and answer_ ing, or leaving OP in the dark).

Comment: "I gave five dollars to John" sounds rather unusual to my ears. I think it would usually be triggered by context, eg "I've given the kids their fare home ... I gave Tracy and Luke three dollars, and I gave five dollars to John." This fronts the amount given to John, rather than John, emphasising the difference in amount given. _But either usage is 'correct', and the S-V-IO-DO usage more common.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the sentences is not in the meaning but in the construction This concerns "the dative shift" - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift.

The difference centres on **the double object construction (DOC)** and **the oblique dative (OD)**

Taking much from that article:

*He said to me something.

To say is strongly monotransitive but has an optional adverbial complement.

He said something.

He said something quietly.

He said something about her.

He said something to her.

The object of "to say" is always the actual words or a description of what is/was/will be said. It can have no other object.

1 .....He.......said.................to me........................[that he was happy]

1a Subject....Verb....complement (adverbial)...[object = content clause..]

2a .....He.......said.........[……something]…..........to me.

2b .....He.......said.........[……something]…...about the decision.

2c Subject....Verb ....[........object...........]...complement (adverbial)

There are verbs that have a mandatory adverbial complement - consider

1 *He put.

2 *He put it

3 He put it down/up.

4 He put it to me/over the door/outside.

There are other verbs that have an optional adverbial complement:

5 He gave

6 He gave freely

7 He gave it

8 He gave it freely.

9 He gave it to her.

10 He gave it to her freely.

11 He gave me the book - not you. (acceptable)

12 He gave to me the book - not you.  (archaic/poetic)

13 He gave to me the book - not to you. (archaic/poetic)

14 He gave the book to me - not you.

15 He gave the book to me - not to you.

16 He gave the book me - not you. (irregular/informal)

17 He gave the book me - not to you. (irregular/informal)

*11 is acceptable where the context is unambiguous. It is unlikely that anyone would give another person to a book, and, if that was what was meant, it would be expressed clearly.*

*However: "The king gave him her" would have to have context, and would, in any case, be unlikely to be used.*

.....He.......gave....[the book].................to me

Subject....Verb ....[..object..]... complement (adverbial)

.....He.......gave.........[......me/John...........]......[the book] (acceptable where the context is unambiguous)

**Subject....Verb .........[dative substantive..].......[object]** (Oblique dative)

Subject....Verb ......[complement (adverbial)]..[object]

The **dative** implies a "to" or "for" to the substantive; this then produces a prepositional modifier.

It would seem that

(i) all indirect objects are adverbial complements but

(ii)    not all adverbial complements are indirect objects

(iii)   that adverbial complements may be mandatory or optional.

(iv)    The perceived difference is that the adverbial complement is more closely associated with the verb than the indirect object, and

(v)  **to** has the nuance of movement about it. **For** has the nuance of benefiting.

It is clear that the following adverbial complements are not indirect objects:

He rode his horse to London
The water changed to ice
The horse turned to the left.

POSITION
1a He said nothing to me.
1b To me, he said nothing.
1c He, to me, said nothing.
1d He said, to me, nothing.

2a He said nothing about the matter.
2b About the matter, he said nothing.
2c He, about the matter, said nothing.
2d He said, about the matter, nothing.

In both cases, a and b are natural, but c and d are "clunky"

"He gave me the book", might seem wrong for two reasons
1. "**the** book" indicates a previously mentioned book. "He gave me **a** book" is perfectly normal, as is "He gave me **the book that he had stolen**."
2. There appears to be two direct objects.

The missing "to" gives the appearance of two direct objects. However, the disappearing preposition is something that English accepts:

Answer me + Answer this question = "Answer me this question", -> "Answer **for** me this question"

Ask John + Ask a few questions =  "Ask John a few questions", ->  "Ask a few questions **of** John."

Strike him + strike a heavy blow = "Strike him **with** a heavy blow", or "Strike a heavy blow **at** him.

Compare also
He gave the cake to her for her birthday

He made the cake for her for her birthday

He gave the cake to her willingly

He made the cake for her willingly

He gave the cake willingly to her

He made the cake willingly for her

**To her / for her birthday** are simply two prepositional phrases

But
*He gave the cake for her birthday to her.
*He made the cake for her birthday for her.

Comment: There's also the occasional example of indirect objects used with verbs that are less **benefactive** than they are **privative**, such as a guard *denying **him** entry* to some event.  The cases of *doing someone a favor* and *doing someone harm* seem related, although whether those should use *for* or *to* in their prepositional rewrites is strangely different in the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no essential difference between the different versions of the sentences, and there is certainly no difference in interpretation with respect to somebody having actually received something.

However, there is a subtle difference in the *focus* of the statements.

---

> "I wrote **a letter**—"
>   "Oh, who did you write it to?"
>   "—to John."

Here, the focus in on writing a letter, and the clarification is who it was written to.

---

> "I wrote **John**—"
>   "Oh, what did you write him?"
>   "—a letter."

Here, the focus is on writing to John, and the clarification is what it was. (Note that it could have been a letter, a poem, an email message, and so on.)

---

> "I wrote a letter to John."
>   "I wrote John a letter."

While both versions of the sentence convey exactly the same information, the placement of the nouns subtly shifts the focus.

Comment: The title of this question used a pronominal formulation that may not be acceptable to all native speakers. Dative shift from a verb’s indirect object core argument to a prepositional phrase’s prepositional object may no longer sound quite right when that object is a personal pronoun. In other words, *Give him five bucks* is not fully equivalent to *Give five bucks to him* because that *to him* is jarring in a way that *to John* would not be.